# How to automatically fill inputs in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I cannot modify.
When I execute it, it asks for several user inputs and the user has to type the correct information for the batch file to work properly.

Is there a way to simply put all the inputs as parameters?
Something like:

```
./mybatch.bat -input1 orange -input2 tree -input3 house
```

And have it work automatically, skipping all the input parts.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose a batch like this:

```
:: Test.cmd
@Echo off
Set /P "Host=Enter Host: "
Echo:-------------
Set /P "User=enter user: "
Echo:-------------
Set /P "Pass=Enter pass: "
Echo:-------------
Echo Your__input
Echo Host: %Host%
Echo User: %User%
Echo Pass: %Pass%
Pause
```

And a prepared (may be on the fly) answer file:

```
localhost
me
secret
```

A sample run with input redirection

```
> test < input.txt
Enter Host: -------------
enter user: -------------
Enter pass: -------------
Your__input
Host: localhost
User: me
Pass: secret
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a shell file 'myfile.sh' and include this piece of code in it:

```
./mybatch.bat -input1 orange -input2 tree -input3 house
```

Then you can later run the shell file as

```
sh myfile.sh
```

and you do not need to give the input parameters everytime.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. What I need to know is what am I supposed to put instead of "-input1", "-input2" and "-input3", what is the correct syntax, if there is one.

Comment: batch-file/batch isn't bash.

Comment: No, but the same principle applies: Just create another batch file that contains the exact command line you want, and run that.